# local image is not shown in shiny Rmd app but directly in shiny R app

Tags: css, r, shiny, r-markdown

I have a RMarkdown Shiny app and want to show an image. On top of that image I will show some htmlOutput. A found an example of an R Shiny App that works fine. The image is stored locally in www folder.
But when I try this with an RMarkdown shiny app and copy the complete R code into an R code chunk this will not work.

Here is the code of the R shiny app. For Rmd file with code just create a new RMarkdown shiny document and add a new R code chunk with the following lines as code. I had formatting problems with inserting the Rmd file in this question template so I was not able to publish it with Rmd code ...

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Count"),
  
  # Sidebar
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("txt1", "Enter the text1 to display below:",
                value = 52)
    ),
    # Show an image with a counter
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
         column(
          6,
          div(
            style = "
                   margin-left:0%;
                    display: inline-block;
                    text-align: center;
                    position: absolute;
                ",
            img(
              src = "/Schema_BB_NKB_real.jpg",
              height = 400,
              width = 800,
              style = "  position: relative;"
            ),
            span(htmlOutput("default1"),
                 style = "
              color: orange;
              font-size: 20px;
              font-style: bold;
                 position: relative;
                 text-align: center;
                 width: 100px;
                 top: -100px;
                 "
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$default1 <- renderUI({
    str2 <- input$txt1
    str1 <- paste("You")
    HTML(paste("str1:", input$txt1, sep = '<br/>'))
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I tried something with addRessourcePath but this works only when i use an absolute path to my folder. This will not work anymore when I copy this app to my server.

Here now should be the Rmd file as code:

````
---
title: "text on image"
author: "me"
date: "2023-12-17"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r shiny app, echo=FALSE}
library(shiny)
# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Count"),
  
  # Sidebar
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("txt1", "Enter the text1 to display below:",
                value = 52)
    ),
    # Show an image with a counter
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
         column(
          6,
          div(
            style = "
                   margin-left:0%;
                    display: inline-block;
                    text-align: center;
                    position: absolute;
                ",
            img(
              src = "/Schema_BB_NKB_real.jpg",
              height = 400,
              width = 800,
              style = "  position: relative;"
            ),
            span(htmlOutput("default1"),
                 style = "
              color: orange;
              font-size: 20px;
              font-style: bold;
                 position: relative;
                 text-align: center;
                 width: 100px;
                 top: -100px;
                 "
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$default1 <- renderUI({
    str2 <- input$txt1
    str1 <- paste("You")
    HTML(paste("str1:", input$txt1, sep = '<br/>'))
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```
````

Comment: Since your problem arises from using `rmd runtime:shiny` document, it makes more sense to include that code and not what I presume to be a working shiny app. To format a rmd file when asking a question, wrap the entire contents with 4 back ticks. ```` that will allow you to display the code chunks properly.

Comment: Thanks Jamie - i now edited the question and included the Rmd file. I did not found the hint with the 4 back ticks yet ...